# Magento 2 : Website Search Functionality is not Accurate

Tags: magento2.3, search, catalogsearch

The search functionality is no longer accurate and provide irrelevant products on my Magento2.3 site.

For e.g. when one search for 'shirt' other products appear. How can this be solved so that my search gives appropriate result.

Comment: What other products appear in your example? Any URLs to test?